# I created form using angular 11

Tags: angular

I want to update my array list according to return value of getItemTotal() function and put in to database, in this case i used [(ngModel)] any try lot of methods but i cannot do this , how can i update my itemsArry list after function call??

my home.component.html file is,

```
  <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between">Items Details <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addRow()" >+</button></h4>


      <form action="" #invoiceBody="ngForm">
        <div *ngFor="let obj of itemsArray;let i=index">
      <div class="row" >

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label>Item No</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemNo{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.itemNo" >
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label>Unit Price</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="unitPrice{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.unitPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="quantity{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="obj.quantity">

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <label>Total</label><br>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="total{{i}}" [value]="getItemTotal(obj)" [(ngModel)]="obj.total" >

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1" *ngIf="i!=0">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-top:30px" (click)="removeRow(i)">-</button>
        </div>



       </div>

      </div>


      </form>


      </div>
```

my home.components.ts file is,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'



class itemObject {
  itemNo:any;
  unitPrice:number=0;
  quantity:number=0;
  total:number=0;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

itemObject=new itemObject()
itemsArray:Array<itemObject>=[
  {
    itemNo:"",
    unitPrice:0,
    quantity:0,
    total:0

  }
]


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  addRow() {
    this.itemsArray.push(this.itemObject)


  }

  removeRow(i: number) {
    this.itemsArray.splice(i)

  }



  getItemTotal(item: itemObject) {
     return (item.quantity && item.unitPrice) ? item.quantity * item.unitPrice:0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ngModel is linked to the same reference of itemObject, that's why it's overwriting data with the added itemObject and you actually calculate "on the fly" the total. It's currently only a user display purpose. You need to save the total on object itself.

Here a quick resolution :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cphu9u?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You better make use of ReactiveFormModule with Array, this is a good guide : https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Edit: the reactiveFormModule version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7w9cv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanx bro, my array is now update correctely. I dont want this getTotal() funtion.

Comment: Thanks , the reactive form version : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7w9cv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: bro i have another question

Comment: yeah what is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

you can not mix `[(ngModel)]`and `[value]`. You can use

```
     <input type="number" class="form-control" 
                 [ngModel]="getItemTotal(obj)" 
                 (ngModelChange)="obj.total=$event">
```

BTW Really, as total is always "unitPrice*quantity" you can not use (ngModelChange) and make the input read only.

Another important thing is that you should use

```
return (item.quantity && item.unitPrice) ? (+item.quantity) * (+item.unitPrice):0;
```

See the + this makes Angular consider always as number the value

**Update** for the total sum use a getter

```
  get totalSum(){
       return this.itemsArray.reduce((a,b)=>b.unitPrice && b.itemQuantity? 
                a+(+b.unitPrice)*(+b.itemQuantity):a,0)
    }
```

and in .html

```
{{totalSum}}
```

A getter makes that any change Angular execute the function. You shoul use carefully -it's not good idea to has a several serverals "getter" because can result a poor performance (if only has a few data as our problem, is perfectly valid)

Comment: but still my array total field is not updated

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer